# Why does my database keep changing numbers in a certain column in my csv file when I upload it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

When I import a csv file in my database, it always seems to change the numbers in the id column completely. Could this be due to the encoding?[This is the link to my csv file. The column is stop_id](http://linkireland.info/stops.csv)

Comment: if the column is `autonumeric` the `id` will keep growing with each insert.

Comment: Also - even if you delete a bunch of records, the index remembers where it was.  So if you delete record id=100, the next record will still be 101.

Comment: No Its not that. And many rows which I view as different values in my csv editor all come up as the same number

Comment: You need to provide more detail on how you're importing your file and the definition of the table you're importing it into

Comment: You need to provide the definition of the table.

Answer (score 0):

In your question as well as in your comment, you talk about *numbers* for the column `stop_id`. Did you by any chance define that column as a `numeric` data type?

Only the first 31 `stop_id`'s are numeric:

```
stop_id,stop_name,stop_lat,stop_lon
"700000000240","Belfast (Europa Bus Centre)","54.5945926369851","-5.93660082131046"
"700000003388","Sprucefield (Shopping Centre)","54.4872433773613","-6.06597923051899"
"700000003812","Newry (College of Further Education)","54.1768023042176","-6.34321285594727"
```

After that you get strings:

```
"810B137531","Cannistown School","53.6212628722786","-6.66677004511465"
"8210B1340201","Hacketstown (Kealys)","52.8652215308509","-6.55839857023041"
"8210B136211","Rathvilly (Opp Post Office)","52.8804440197479","-6.69566912436171"
"8210B136231","Hacketstown (Opp Kealys)","52.86533977541","-6.55851347138918"
```

And later you get this:

```
"gen:31400:3017:1:2","Portadown (Danske Bank)","54.4229216097347","-6.44325546877619"
"gen:31400:4183:1:2","Rathfriland","54.2365511195376","-6.15840771694293"
"gen:31400:4183:1:3","Rathfriland","54.2365511195376","-6.15840771694293"
```

Or did you define the column as text, but too short?

In general, your csv file is ok.